# get record ids after bulk insert in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.4 I want to get record ids after I insert them in the table. here's data that I want to insert, it stored in array

```
$data = [
  [
    "count" => "100",
    "start_date" => 1515628800
  ],
  [
    "count" => "102",
    "start_date" => 1515715200
  ]
];
```

here I insert the array of items at once

```
\Auth::user()->schedule()->insert($data);
```

but this method returns `boolean` and I want to get ids(or all columns) of these new items after they been inserted, how should I do this? it doesn't matter if it will be done with `eloquent` or `querybuilder`. I already tried `insertGetId` method, but it doesn't seem to work with multidimensional array. if its not possible with laravel, what would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: iterate over and then use insertGetId()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround: Select highest PK value and you should know what values they had. You might need locking to prevent a race with other users though.

edit:

LOCK TABLES schedule WRITE;

// Select last ID

UNLOCK TABLES;

the list of id's is then the `last id - insert count`

Comment: can you please be more specific, after I insert the data I should lock the table and retrieve last 2(for example) records?

Comment: I've never seen someone use this in a real project. Are there any downsides of this method?

Comment: To be honest: I don't know because I haven't tried. Howevery, there are not many other options. Also locking the table is not perfect when you have a lot of simultanious users.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin yes, because operations are not synchronous across nodes, you could insert 1000, some other unrelated process/application etc. could add 1 more as well during/after than, and then when you go to get the last one you are 1 (or however many) out.

Wrap your query in a transaction. Calculate the IDs first, then insert with them specified. That way if there's a race condition (like the above), and something can't be inserted, the transaction will undo all operations and you can do whatever you need to do to resolve (i.e. try again or something).

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to generate the id's server side any time I run into this issue but you have to make sure the id's are unique. Also, you can do it for exactly the tables you need (not the entire database). Hope this helps.